# How to you put a checkbox in a django.contrib.auth.forms UserCreationForm

Tags: python, django, forms, checkbox

I have multiple fields in my Django UserCreationForm including the already included username, password 1, and password 2. I have also added and email field. I am unable to add a checkbox.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    is_teacher = forms.BooleanField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['is_teacher', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

I want there to be a checkbox to declare if the user wants to register as a teacher or as a student.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
    <div class="container row">
        <form method="POST" class='input-field col s6 offset-s3' >
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset>
                <legend>
                    Sign Up:
                </legend>
                {{form.as_p}}
            </fieldset>
            <br>
              <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light green accent-2" type="submit" name="action">Submit
                <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
              </button>
            <br><br>
            <div>
                <small>
                    Already have an account?  <a href='{% url "login"%}'>Sign In</a>
                </small>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
{% endblock  %}
```

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html')
```

Comment: Do you want a custom `User` model that has this teacher/student field or do you want to add the user to a teacher/student `Group`?

Comment: I want the teacher/student field so that I can add the user to a specified group. But for the sake of the question, I am looking to make a teacher/student field.

Comment: It's fairly easy to add a field to a form. Any fields that you add to a form must still be in `Meta.fields` though

Comment: I am unclear of how to add the field. I tried is_teacher = forms.BooleanField(required=True). And then I added 'is_teacher' to my form field. However, when I try to register and account, no checkbox appears on the form.

Comment: You need to change your template to render the field

Comment: Because I am using a UserRegisterForm, all I have in the template is {{form.as_p}. I don't have code in my templates for each field.

Comment: Can you share your view, template and form with the field added?

Comment: Your view, form and template look fine. Are you sure you are going through that view? Can you share your urls? Maybe raise an exception to confirm you are going through that view

Answer (score 0):

You already added the  BooleanField in django form here:

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
is_teacher = forms.BooleanField(required=True)


class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['is_teacher', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

looks good you only need to add the it to your html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}    <div class="container row">
       <form method="POST" class='input-field col s6 offset-s3' >
           {% csrf_token %}
           <fieldset>
               <legend>
                   Sign Up:
               </legend>
               {{form.as_p}}
           </fieldset>
           <br>
             <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light green accent-2" type="submit" name="action">Submit
               <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
             </button>
           <br><br>
           <div>
               <small>
                   Already have an account?  <a href='{% url "login"%}'>Sign In</a>
               </small>
           </div>



         <div name="new is teacher checkbox">
   
        {{form.is_teacher}}


         </div>
  

       </form>
       </div> {% endblock  %}
```

You can access the value of is_teacher in views too by  forms.cleaned_data.get('is_teacher')